# Does "take the crown" mean anything like "take the cake" or anything at all?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

I just spontaneously used the phrase "take the crown" while complimenting someone's work.
"Harry, this one takes the crown. Keep it up."

Does it exist as an idiom?
Does it actually mean "best of all" or something like "take the cake"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***To take the crown*** is a synonym for ***to win*** - see the 2nd meaning [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/win).

Comment: It often does and *Takes the crown/cake/biscuit…* don't actually need any competition.

*Harry, this one takes the crown. Keep it up* could also refer to the best of a fine batch, without anything to *win*.

Comment: It's not in common usage though, and it has connotations of overthrowing the previous crown-holder, like a war for the kingdom.  I think it's a bit of a weird thing to say in the context.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Google returns ~166,000 results when searching for "but this one takes the crown". That's not *very* common, but I believe it's enough to establish it as an idiom. I agree it may not be best suited in the given example, but we don't know the full context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I stand corrected!  I guess it's just me then.  I wonder if it's an Americanism.